# Does Control Zone touchpad in HP notebooks have standard LMB/RMB clicks at the bottom of touchpad?

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I wanted to buy: http://www.x-kom.pl/p/203762-ultrabook-15-6-hp-envy-15-x360-u000ew-i5-4210u-4gb-1000-win81.html#

but now I see it does not have normal touchpad but this one which does not work as it should in Spectre 13. The deal is that every video says about those new features (which will be outdated when Windows 9 will come by) not about if it still has standard LMB/RMB click.

Question: Does or does not Control Zone touchpade have mechanical left and right mouse button area at the bottom of it as every other touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

***YES IT DOES***
I just bought an hp Envy with control zone and all i do is ignore the shaded area. it still has LMB/RMB click as long as its not in the shaded area. The control zone is also designed for windows 8.1, so there is a booklet inside the box with all the gestures. anyways I repeat ***The RBM/LBM Does Work!***
Happy Helping you!